# Partials not being rendered on dynamic webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, templating, express-handlebars

I created a handlebar for my index.html file so when user visits http://localhost:3000/ [the root] it displays a dynamic version of my index.html. However, when the page loads, everything loads except for the partials I have included?

Here is the part of my page handlebar where I put the partials (newView.handlebar):

```
.
.
<main class="twit-container">

    {{#each twitData}}    //will iterate/insert data for the amount of objects in the array being passed in server.js
        {{> newTwit}}  //the name of my partial template
    {{/each}}

</main>
.
.etc...
```

and below is my server.js code (where i think the issue might be):

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var rawData = fs.readFileSync('./twitData.json');
var twitData = JSON.parse(rawData); //get the tweet data (text/authors)


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.status(200).render('newView', {data: twitData});

});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '404.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("== Server is listening on port", port);
});
```

Comment: You're not sending `twits` to the view. Either you're not showing us all the code, or you need to send: `twits` to render.

Comment: is having it as part of the view handlebar not enough? is the array twitData not being applied to the twits (because they are partials of the view handlebar) in server.js?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you're saying. You're using `twits` on your handlebars view, but you don't have a reference to `twits` anywhere in your code, so what is `twits`? where are you setting it? How handlebars is supposed to know what `twits` is if you're not sending it to the view.

Comment: The partial {{> newTwit}} is the reference, as newTwit is a handlebar I made (not included) sorry i thought that was implied

Comment: I'm not asking about the partial, I'm asking about `twits` in `{{#each twits}}` **what is twits**, your partial won't be rendered if `twits` is empty.

Comment: if im not mistaken, twits (or twitData after the edit) is an array of objects. So the twitData I am passing in server.js is being captured by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over `twitData` but you're never sending it to the view.

```
<main class="twit-container">

    {{#each twitData}}    //will iterate/insert data for the amount of objects in the array being passed in server.js
        {{> newTwit}}  //the name of my partial template
    {{/each}}

</main>
```

You need to send it like this:

```
res.status(200).render('newView', { twitData });
```

Otherwise you will need to use: `{{#each data}}`.

Comment: I changed the key to 'data' and it now works. Thanks!